# How do I set up a Strapi App on a Phusion Passenger NodeJS environment

Tags: node.js, passenger, strapi, phusion

I have this hoster that use Phusion Passenger for the NodeJS environment and I want to run my Strapi App on it.

For now I did the following:

1. Strapi and the node modules are installed on the server
2. The app is connected to the database
3. the app.js can start fine

I don't know how to configure my app.js file to make it launch Strapi

I did something like this but I'm pretty sure this is wrong:

```
const http = require("http");
const hostname = "127.0.0.1";
const port = "passenger";
const strapi = require("@strapi/strapi");

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain");
  res.end("Hello World! NodeJS");
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at https://somary.fr/`);
  strapi().start();
});
```

How do I configure my app.js file to finally access my strapi app?

Answer (score 0):

I'm deploying a Strapi@4.3.8 app on Phusion Passenger.

Here is my updated app.js file:

```
const strapi = require("@strapi/strapi");
strapi({ dir: "./build" }).start();
```

To create the build folder, you need to run:

```
npm run build
```

I hope I helped.

Answer (score 0):

In my case Phusion Passenger was explicitly looking for a server.js (not app.js | index.js) on my managed hosting (plesk, phusion passenger, ...).

Also pm2 and mysql were not installed, since access is restricted to install stuff globally. So I had to make a way around.

> CAREFUL: in config/server.js is a file dedicated to configure your
> server. Though this is not the one you want to set as the entry point
> of your app.

Here's what I did:

1. install pm2 and mysql

```
npm install pm2 mysql
```

2. create a server.js file (in my root: ./server.js) with following contents

```js
const strapi = require('@strapi/strapi');
strapi(/* {...} */).start();
```

3. rebuild my admin webapp

```
npm run build
```

4. build my app for production

```
npm run production
```

ps: make sure to have the proper ports and url set up in your .env file